# AngularJS can't pass $index from bootstrap modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm banging my head against the wall here. I'm using ng-repeat to populate a table. Inside each row i have 2 buttons, one for updating the row content and for uploading files. The upload button opens a bootstrap modal window, where the user selects the files and clicks on submit.

The submit button uses ng-click to run a function which uses $index as parameter. But the $index value is always the same no matter which row is selected.

The thing I don't understand is that I use the exact same syntax (although outside of a modal window) on my update button, which works just fine.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search " ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
   <td>{{$index}}</td>
   <td ng-hide="idHidden" ng-bind="item.Id"></td>
   <td ng-hide="titleHidden">
      <span  data-ng-hide="editMode">{{item.Title}}</span>
      <input  type="text" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-model="item.Title" data-ng-required />
   <td> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary uploadBtn" data-ng-show="editMode" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">Upload file  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></button>
      <!-- Upload Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="uploadModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="uploadModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                  <h3 class="modal-title" id="uploadModalLabel">Options</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                  <h4>Upload Documents</h4>
                  <form>
                     <div class="form-group">
                        <select  data-ng-model="type" class="form-control" id="fileTypeSelect">
                           <option value="Policy">Policy</option>
                           <option value="SOP">SOP</option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
                           <input type="file" id="file">
                           </span>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="uploadAttachment($index, type)">Upload</button>
                  </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" data-ng-hide="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = true;" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Edit <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>
      <button type="button" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; updateItem($index)" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      <button type="button" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
      </td>`
```

JS:

```
$scope.uploadAttachment = function executeUploadAttachment(index, type) {
var listname = "Risk Register";
var id = $scope.items[index].Id;
console.log(indexID);
readFile("uploadControlId").done(function(buffer, fileName) {
    uploadAttachment(type, id, listname, fileName, buffer).done(function() {
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error in uploading attachment");
    })
}).fail(function(err) {
    alert("error in reading file content");
});
}
```

So the function `uploadAttachment($index, type)` which is triggered by ng-click doesn't pass the right index number. It always passes the same, no matter what row it is clicked in.

I have omitted some of the code that is irrelevant. If needed i can provide the whole thing.

Any suggestions to what I am missing?

**Edit:**

I have tried to implement **DonJuwe** suggestions.

I have added this inside my controller:

```
$scope.openModal = function(index) {
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'www.test.xxx/App/uploadModal.html',
    controller: 'riskListCtrl',
    resolve: {
        index: function() {
            return index;
        }
    }
});
};
```

This is my modal template:

```
 <div class="modal-header">
   <h3 class="modal-title" id="uploadModalLabel">Options</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
   <h4>Upload Documents</h4>
   <form>
      <div class="form-group">
         <select  data-ng-model="type" class="form-control" id="fileTypeSelect">
            <option value="Policy">Policy</option>
            <option value="SOP">SOP</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="file" id="file">
            </span>
         </div>
         <br>
         <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="uploadAttachment($index, type)">Upload</button>
   </form>
   </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

And finally my function which resides inside RiskListCtrl (the only controller i use):

```
  $scope.uploadAttachment = function executeUploadAttachment(index, type) {
var listname = "Risk Register";
var id = $scope.items[index].Id;
console.log(indexID);
readFile("uploadControlId").done(function(buffer, fileName) {
    uploadAttachment(type, id, listname, fileName, buffer).done(function() {
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error in uploading attachment");
    })
}).fail(function(err) {
    alert("error in reading file content");
});
}
```

It seems that `$scope.items[index].Id` is empty. Error: `Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined`

Comment: `<td>{{$index}}</td>` is always the same as well?

Comment: Nope `<td>{{$index}}</td>` show the correct number.

Comment: And you are referring to this line where `$index` is the same? `<button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="uploadAttachment($index, type)">Upload</button>`

Comment: Yes the function `uploadAttachment($index, type)` doesn't get the right index number. I will edit my op to make it more clear.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Not really, because this is used inside production enviroment. So alot of the calls in the script depend on internal security.

Comment: just part with ngrepeat and modal, with sample data

Comment: seems like problem with scope, but without working sample not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modal window has its own scope. That means you need to **resolve data** you want to pass into the modal's scope. To do so, use `resolve` within the modals [`open(options)`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) method.

Before I will give you an example, I want to suggest having only one modal for all your table items. This will let you keep a single template where you can easily use `id` (now, you create a template for each of your table items which is not valid). Just call a controller function and pass your `$index`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary uploadBtn" data-ng-show="editMode" ng-click="openModal($index)">Upload file  <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i></button>
```

In your controller, create the modal instance and refer to the template:

```
$scope.openModal = function(index) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myPath/myTemplate.html',
        controller: 'MyModalCtrl',
        resolve: {
            index: function() {
                return index;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Now you can access `index` in your `MyModalCtrl`'s scope by injecting `index`:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).controller('MyModalCtrl', function($scope, index) {
    $scope.index = index;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are getting the index value outside model then you can also use ng-click and then call a function in your controller and store the index value in a temporary variable and then when you are using submit button then just take make another variable and assign the value of temporary variable to your variable. for example:

```
     <button type="button" data-ng-show="editMode" data-ng-click="editMode = false; updateItem($index)" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
```

and then make a function in your controller

```
$scope.updateItem = functon(index)
{
$scope.tempVar = index;
}

now use the value of tempVar in you function 

 $scope.uploadAttachment = function executeUploadAttachment(index, type) {
var index = tempVar;            //assign the value of tempvar to index
var listname = "Risk Register";
var id = $scope.items[index].Id;
console.log(indexID);
readFile("uploadControlId").done(function(buffer, fileName) {
    uploadAttachment(type, id, listname, fileName, buffer).done(function() {
        alert("success");
    }).fail(function() {
        alert("error in uploading attachment");
    })
}).fail(function(err) {
    alert("error in reading file content");
});
}
```